# UDP client / server ....include 16-bit message sequence number for filtering duplicates

Tags: java, udpclient

my assignment includes sending an image file using UDP service (using java I implemented that successfully). My professor asked to include:

> "The exchanged data messages must also have a header part for the sender to include 16-bit message sequence number for duplicate filtering at the receiver end"

How to do this?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: using a regular method ive managed to trasnfer a image using UDP...this was an additional task for us....

Answer (score 3):

I assume to create your UDP packet, you are using a ByteArrayOutputStream to generate the data. If that is the case, just Wrap a DataOutputStream on top of that ByteArrayOutputStream, and call writeInt(somesequenceNumber) before writing the image data to the stream.

on the receive side, do the opposite, wrap a DataInputStream around a ByteArrayInputStream, and call readInt() to get the sequence number. From there you can check whether you have already received this packet.

Something like

Write Side

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

dos.writeInt(sequenceNumber++);
dos.writeInt(imageDataLength);
dos.write(imageData);

dos.flush();

byte[] udpPacketBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Read Side

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(udpPacketBytes);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
int sequenceNumber = dis.readInt();
if (seenSequenceNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(sequenceNumber)))
{
    int imageLength = dis.readInt();
    byte[] imageData = new byte[imageLength];
    dis.read(imageData);
}
```

where seenSequenceNumbers is some Set

Answer (score 1):

For a 16-bit value I would use DataOutputStream.writeShort() and DataInputSTream readShort()/readUnsignedShort(). writeInt() and readInt() are for 32-bit values.  If you want to avoid duplicates, a 32-bit value may be a better choice in any case. ;)